# how to rename javascript object function hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, hasownproperty

hasOwnProperty is long and makes my code unreadable with long chained if statements.

Is there a way to rename hasOwnProperty to 'hop', 'has' or just 'h' so i can say something like

```
 if(req.body.h('first_name') && req.body.h('last_name'))
 {
    //....
 }
```

Comment: Do you *need* `hasOwnProperty`? Because you can just use `in` but that also checks the prototype chain `'first_name' in req.body`

Comment: You can just do `if(req.body.first_name && req.body.last_name)`

Comment: If you really need to rename the prototype function, just assign it to something which suits you better like var h = Object.hasOwnProperty;

Comment: @ponury-kostek only if `null`, or `""` are not supposed to be valid values. They might be - you might have a `first_name` property but it's explicitly set to an empty value, which could be *different* to a missing property.

Comment: @VLAZ I think it's data from web form so those fields are always set and he want to check that someone fill them

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt: That would require `Function.prototype.call` to invoke it, unless you did `var h = Function.call.bind(Object.hasOwnProperty);`

Comment: @ponury-kostek if the fields are sent every time, then `hasOwnProperty` is redundant. It only makes sense to call it if they might not be there.

Answer (score 2):

You could just make a reference to the original [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method.

```js
Object.prototype.h = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

const data = {a:1};

if(data.h('a')){
  console.log('success');
}else{
  console.log('false');
}
```

Comment: I would make a reference to the original, but it's not wise to add that reference to the prototype - - changes to prototypes are discouraged. Just set a variable equal to `.hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: how would i set a variable equal to '.hasOwnProperty' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

```
Object.prototype.hop = function(p) {
  return this.hasOwnProperty(p);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
Object.prototype.hop = function(p) {
  return this.hasOwnProperty(p);
}

const object1 = new Object();
object1.property1 = 42;

console.log(object1.hop('property1')); // true
console.log(object1.hop('property2')); // false
```

Comment: thanks on nodejs i actually get an error when starting the server "the options [hop] is not supported" - not sure why

Answer (score 0):

I'd just create a utility that receives a list of properties to check.

```
function hasProperties(obj, ...names) {
  return names.every(n => obj.hasOwnProperty(n))
}

 if(hasProperties(req.body, 'first_name', 'last_name'))
 {
    //....
 }
```

But `.hasOwnProperty()` calls are usually avoidable with shorter checks, unless you actually allow `Object.prototype` extensions in your code.

To answer the question directly, yes, but your desired solution would require such `Object.prototype` extensions. I think they're far more trouble than they're worth.